# how to slide object on Oracle Reports Builder

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

On reports builder, some object changing status ( visible or hidden).According this status,  how to drag/slide other object's location?

for example; object2 down object1 and if object1 is hidden, object2's location slide up (object1's location)

Answer (score 2):

Put your objects in frames that have `Vertical Elasticity` set to `variable` or `contract`. Then put a `format trigger` on the frame(s) that need to be shown (return true) or hidden (return false).